# What is the definition of "Recent" in Azure Devops Pipelines and how to change it?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In an Azure Devops project, I see all the "Recent" pipeline runs under the Recent tab.

The list includes pipelines not run for 16 months - as well as those run this week, for example.

How do I customise the list to show only those run in the past month (for example)?

NOTES:

1. I am NOT talking about the lifetime of the releases themselves, which I know can be customised in  the Project Properties --> Pipelines.
2. I do not want to delete the old pipelines - just not see them in the "Recent" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows 50（default value） pipelines in recent tab according to our backend API test. I am afraid that you can't customise the list to show.

Comment: Thank you. That is a shame as "Recent" really just means "last 50 pipelines". OK, perhaps I will request it as a feature.